# Undefined behaviour whist concatenating strings in C

Tags: c, pointers, string-concatenation, c-strings, function-definition

I'm writing a C program that would concatenate all the lines ("`\n`" included) whilst saving the pointer to the last character of the final string. However, I do not get the result I expected. What could be the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node {
  struct Node *next;
  struct Node *prev;
};

struct Node *CreateNewNode() {
  struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  return newNode;
}

struct PieceTable {
  char *buffer;
  char *ptr_to_last_character;
} PT;

void strconcatenate(char *source) {
  size_t source_len = strlen(source);
  size_t buffer_len = strlen(PT.buffer);
  PT.buffer = realloc(PT.buffer, buffer_len + source_len + 1);
  while (*source)
    *PT.ptr_to_last_character++ = *source++;
  *PT.ptr_to_last_character = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char input_line[1024];

  PT.buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
  *PT.buffer = '\0';
  PT.ptr_to_last_character = PT.buffer;

  struct Node *new_node = CreateNewNode();
  new_node->next = NULL;
  new_node->prev = NULL;

  strconcatenate("Lorem ipsum\n");
  strconcatenate("dolor sit amet\n");
  strconcatenate("consectetur adipiscing elit\n");

  printf("%s", PT.buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit
```

**Output:**

```
etur adipiscing elit
```

Comment: "I do not get the result I expected." - What did you expect?  Please edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: @marko - look at the bottom of the post

Comment: @Jonathan S. What is this code   struct Node *new_node = CreateNewNode();
  new_node->next = NULL;
  new_node->prev = NULL; doing in the program?

Comment: realloc invalidates pointers since it allocates new storage and moves the contents there.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It is supposed to do "nothing" since it is a part of a larger program, but I've added it because I've found out that if I remove it I get a totally different result. I suppose there is an Undefined Behaviour somewhere.

Comment: @JonathanS. Keeping the pointer to the terminating zero does not make any sense because in any case you need to call strlen. So the function in whole does not make sense.

Comment: @stark I see, that's interesting. Is there an elegant way to fix this?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You're right, I actually need the pointer of the character *before* the terminating zero.

Comment: Calling realloc for every byte is very inefficient.  Using the global PT is not good programming style.  Store offsets into the buffer instead of pointers and just realloc at some larger boundary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You realloc `PT.buffer`, but you don't update `PT.ptr_to_last_character`. That causes undefined behavior when the `realloc` can't just expand the current allocation and instead returns a new larger region at a different address, leaving `ptr_to_last_character` pointing to the old memory.

Probably better is to store the length of the buffer rather than a pointer to the last character so you don't have to worry about invalidating it.

Comment: Thanks, I actually need the last character for optimization purposes. I've wrapped my head for a while, but still haven't found a proper fix.

Comment: @jonathan simply store the count, then there is nothing to update

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I actually need the *pointer* to the last character, otherwise, I would've implemented a strcat

Comment: @JonathanS - `char *buffer, size_t count` has generally the same space requirements as your structure, but the math is slightly easier. You can always recover the pointer to the last character or *one beyond* from this whenever needed.

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat:* Paul already found the issue, but since you say you *need* a pointer ...

You can adjust the "last" pointer by saving/restoring the offset:

```
ptrdiff_t offset = PT.ptr_to_last_character - PT.buffer;
PT.buffer = realloc(PT.buffer, buffer_len + source_len + 1);
PT.ptr_to_last_character = PT.buffer + offset;
```

---

There are some other cleanup issues that I've annotated in the full code below. `#if 0` wraps old/original code. `#if 1` wraps new/refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct Node {
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
};

struct Node *
CreateNewNode()
{
    struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    // NOTE/WARN: this was moved from main to be more general
#if 1
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
#endif

    return newNode;
}

struct PieceTable {
    char *buffer;
    char *ptr_to_last_character;
} PT;

void
strconcatenate(char *source)
{
    size_t source_len = strlen(source);
    size_t buffer_len = strlen(PT.buffer);

    // NOTE/BUG: after the realloc, PT.buffer can change but
    // PT.ptr_to_last_character is pointing within the _old_ buffer
    // we need to recalc using an offset
#if 0
    PT.buffer = realloc(PT.buffer, buffer_len + source_len + 1);
#else
    ptrdiff_t offset = PT.ptr_to_last_character - PT.buffer;
    PT.buffer = realloc(PT.buffer, buffer_len + source_len + 1);
    PT.ptr_to_last_character = PT.buffer + offset;
#endif

    while (*source)
        *PT.ptr_to_last_character++ = *source++;

    *PT.ptr_to_last_character = '\0';
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char input_line[1024];

    // NOTE/BUG: sizeof(char) is _always_ 1 by definition
#if 0
    PT.buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
#else
    PT.buffer = malloc(2);
#endif
    *PT.buffer = '\0';
    PT.ptr_to_last_character = PT.buffer;

    // NOTE/WARN: this isn't used anywhere
    struct Node *new_node = CreateNewNode();

    // NOTE/WARN: this would be better inside CreateNewNode
#if 0
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->prev = NULL;
#endif

    strconcatenate("Lorem ipsum\n");
    strconcatenate("dolor sit amet\n");
    strconcatenate("consectetur adipiscing elit\n");

    printf("%s", PT.buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters it is unclear why in this statement there are allocated two bytes instead of one byte.

```
PT.buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
*PT.buffer = '\0';
```

Within the function this statement

```
size_t buffer_len = strlen(PT.buffer);
```

does not make sense taking into account that you already have a pointer to the terminating zero. So it is just inefficient.

After the call of `realloc`

```
PT.buffer = realloc(PT.buffer, buffer_len + source_len + 1);
```

the pointer `PT.ptr_to_last_character` can be invalid.

Also you should check whether the memory allocation was successful. Otherwise the pointer `PT.buffer` can be set to NULL in case of a failure.

The function can be implemented the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct PieceTable {
  char *buffer;
  char *ptr_to_last_character;
} PT;

int strconcatenate( const char *source ) 
{
    int success = 1;
    
    size_t n = PT.ptr_to_last_character - PT.buffer;
    
    size_t source_len = strlen( source );
    
    if ( source_len != 0 )
    {
        char *tmp = realloc( PT.buffer, n + source_len + 1 );
        
        if ( ( success = tmp != NULL ) )
        {
            PT.buffer = tmp;
            PT.ptr_to_last_character = PT.buffer + n;

            while ( ( *PT.ptr_to_last_character = *source++ ) ) ++PT.ptr_to_last_character;
        }
    }
    
    return success;
}   

int main(void) 
{
    PT.buffer = malloc( sizeof(char) );
    *PT.buffer = '\0';
    PT.ptr_to_last_character = PT.buffer;
    
    strconcatenate( "Lorem ipsum\n" );
    strconcatenate( "dolor sit amet\n" );
    strconcatenate( "consectetur adipiscing elit\n" );

    puts( PT.buffer );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Also take into account that instead of this manually written loop

```
while ( ( *PT.ptr_to_last_character = *source++ ) ) ++PT.ptr_to_last_character;
```

you could use the standard C string function `strcat` or `strcpy` that will be more efficient.

In this case you function can look the following way

```
int strconcatenate( const char *source ) 
{
    int success = 1;
    
    size_t n = PT.ptr_to_last_character - PT.buffer;
    
    size_t source_len = strlen( source );
    
    if ( source_len != 0 )
    {
        char *tmp = realloc( PT.buffer, n + source_len + 1 );
        
        if ( ( success = tmp != NULL ) )
        {
            PT.buffer = tmp;
            PT.ptr_to_last_character = PT.buffer + n;

            strcpy( PT.ptr_to_last_character, source );
            
            PT.ptr_to_last_character += source_len;
        }
    }
    
    return success;
}
```